# Play video in a circular view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, custom-controls, mpmovieplayercontroller

How can I play a video in a circular view using `MPMoviePlayerController`. Is it possible to set the frame like a circle?

Please give me your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering what you can read in `MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference`:

**Consider a movie player view to be an opaque structure. You can add your own custom subviews to layer content on top of the movie but you must never modify any of its existing subviews.**

I think you are not allowed to change the frame, but you can add a subview and use it like a mask.

```
UIImageView *circle = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"]];
[containerView addSubview:circle];
[circle release];
```

Here there is `MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference`:http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thank you Beppe for your suggestion. When i tried with above code like i have taken a circle image and added as a overlay view to the video player view, when i did this i am not able to see the picture which is at corners of the circle like video player has the frame (100,200,300,300) which is a square and when we place a circle on top of it, 4 side corners will be shown to the user or if we hide it with masking then that part of the video is not visible to the user.

Comment: If you add a mask, you're going to lose the part covered, and there is not a workaround for this issue. If you want a square pass through a circle, you have to transform it, altering its proportions.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for you valuable time Beppe.